# Auto Refresh a div without loading from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

example

```
 <script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#div').load('another.page');
}, 1000);
    </script>
```

i dont want 'another.page' to load i just want to refreh the the '#div' div is it possible
if it is how

thank you

Comment: If you don't want to load something new into the DIV, what do you mean by refresh it?

Comment: If you don't load any content in the div from another page, everytime you modify it in the same view, it will refresh automatically (you don't need any function to do it). Could you explain us what are you trying to do with an example?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is to re-render the `DIV` automatically. So there are a number of ways you can force an `element` to re-render (without a reload) - the most effective one I found was to quickly switch the `display` style of the `element` in question.

That is:

Set the `display` property to `none`:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

and then return it to `block`

```
element.style.display = 'block';
```

Here is the working demo of your example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LjqW/).

*Note:* It's pure `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can update the content of a div without reloading the page. It's a bit unclear what you want from your question so I hope this helps.

html

```
<div id="divID"></div>
```

javascript

```
var counter = 1;
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;
    $('#divID').html(newcontent);
    counter++;
}, 1000);
```

Live example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehq72/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't load just a part of the page just like that. But you can load all the page and fetch just the part you want. eg:

```
$.get('anoter_page.html',function(data){
myDiv = $(data).find('#divID');
$('#divID').html(myDiv.html());
})
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wjbc/)